# Tesseract Can't Find Any Languages

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, tesseract, python-tesseract

**UPDATE**
*I have reinstalled tesseract into my 'program files (x86)' folder and now when I run `tesseract --version` it responds with the version rather than saying it isn't recognized as a cmdlet
*

This seems to be a pretty common problem and have been trying different ways to make this program work. I know there are a lot of existing questions similar to mine but since none of the methods I have found work, I am hoping to get some fresh ideas. TIA

**HERE IS THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE:**

"*pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')*"

**AND HERE IS THE CODE I CURRENTLY AM USING:**

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract

images = convert_from_path("CHECK_12-01-22.pdf", 500, poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-23.01.0\Library\bin')
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    fname = 'image' + str(i) + '.png'
    image.save(fname, "PNG")

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
# text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"')
```

I am using Windows 11 and PyCharm.

I have Poppler working, that converts my PDF to Images but when I try to run Tesseract, it says there aren't any languages found. I have tried a few different methods to get it working. First my Environment Variables are set.  [image of environment variable path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dja4P.png)

Then I tried using config in my code.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"')
```

which also didn't work. I've downloaded different language data files and put them in the tessdata folder to no avail.

Comment: This seems like a pretty solid, well put-together question for what it is. Hopefully I can get some help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the system environment variable right? Check with the command:

```
echo $TESSDATA_PREFIX
```

In my environment the system variable is under:
[image]
you should see in this directory the eng files:
[image]

Comment: Yes I did this. But when I use "echo" it literally just outputs "%TESSDATA_PREFIX%"

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/YLz3dTT) <-- Here is a photo of the my files in the folder
[link](https://ibb.co/BBKqbMJ) <-- Here is a photo of my variables

Comment: Have you set the environment variable in your settings? I have on Win10 and `>tesseract --version`
tesseract v5.1.0.20220510
 leptonica-1.78.0 The TRAINDATA file have another filename extension. What happens, if you rename it like in my picture above to eng.traineddata as in the error message?

Comment: But your Error Message search in C:\Program Files (x86)\ not in C:\Program Files. Have you installed 64-bit or 32-bit version from tesseract?

Comment: when i use "tesseract --version" i get this response
"tesseract : The term 'tesseract' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again"

Comment: I reinstalled tesseract-ocr into the program x86 folder and now when i run `tesseract --version` it returns 

`tesseract v5.3.1.20230401
 leptonica-1.83.1
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.1.4) : libpng 1.6.39 : libtiff 4.5.0 : zlib 1.2.13 : libwebp 1.3.0 : libopenjp2 2.5.0
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.6.2 zlib/1.2.13 liblzma/5.2.9 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.4 libzstd/1.5.2
 Found libcurl/8.0.1 Schannel zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.4 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.10.0
`

Comment: Now when I run the code i get this error `pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')`

Comment: I run python 3.11.2 and tesseract, both in 64-bit version. Check if you find now the file eng.traineddata in you tessdata folder and your environment variable is set correctly.

Comment: And don’t forget to adjust your code line to x86 instead of, r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

Answer (score 1):

When starting a tesseract application the tessdata folder needs to be correctly found by tesseract.exe

There are many ways to do that so in a batch file
I may use for a specific case such as MuPDF the first command line in a batch as

```
set TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Apps\PDF\mupdf\mupdf-1.21.0-windows-tesseract\mupdf-1.21.0-windows-tesseract\tessdata
```

OR I may have a prior fall-back pre set in user environment where I have a copy of `eng.traineddata    22.4 MB 17/01/2023, 01:16:15`

[image]
[image]

but to get that to stick for use both now (and in future) it sometimes needs log-out log-in to be used by the next command shell.

So in the above case on windows 10 I did NOT need to logout its available for fresh command shells, but beware shells started before that change, like some file commanders, that need stopping and re-starting.

[image]

Comment: @K J thank you for your response. I mentioned in my question that I did set the environment variables but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am setting them manually in the Environment Variables setting window. my error message says "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/tessdata/eng.traineddata"
Why are the slashes messed up after "Tesseract-OCR"? Maybe it is just a problem with the link

Comment: yes I believe at one point i had it pointing directyly to **Tesseract-OCR\tessdata** but i switched it to just tesseract-ocr

Comment: When I run "print(os.getenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX"))" it returns "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution I was able to find**

```
tessdata_dir_config = "--tessdata-dir 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata\\"

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config=tessdata_dir_config)`
```

I initially was using an x32 bit version while I have a 64 bit operating system so I **uninstalled Tessract-OCR** and found the x86 bit version and **reinstalled** that to my *program files (x86)* folder. I had to point to the **tessdata** before calling the tesseract_cmd. I made the path into a variable that I was able to use as an argument while converting the image to text.